# CSS zIndex troubles. Link inside

Tags: css, z-index

Good evening Stack Overflow, I've got a css issue tonight. I have a fixed-positioned shopping cart at the top of the viewport, and products can be dragged and dropped into the cart. The problem is - the products are showing up behind the cart. I've been playing with the z-indexes and positions of all of the elements in question and can't seem to find anything that works.

http://hub.mhn.co/Store/Product/

I'll admit CSS isn't a strong point for me, I'm hoping someone will see this and know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a z-index to the cart area as well. For example, `z-index: 1` on `#cartControl` made it work fine since the dragging item has a z-index of 10.

Comment: odd, I had z-index set to 3 on #cartControl. But your suggestion worked, thank you!